# Кодировка выдачи гугла

Tags: кодировка, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день.

В общем, пхп получает страницу выдачи гугла:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.google.ru/search?q='.urlencode( $_POST["word"] ));
```

На странице вместо русского текста вопросительные знаки в ромбиках, которые не хотят декодироваться.

Страница передается в js для парсинга, но ни decodeURI ("http://site/те-самые-вопросительные-знаки"), ни urldecode (ответ_от_гугла) в пхп ничего не меняют.

Похоже, что отрабатывает скрипт, переданный вместе с страницей, который и переводит текст на русский. А у меня нет возможности его запустить, ведь получает страницу пхп.

Может, можно как-то запросить у гугла страницу уже в нужной кодировке или каким-то образом перекодировать обычный ответ?

Comment: @dy_ma, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
mb_convert_encoding ( ответ-от-гугла, 'utf-8', 'windows-1251' );
```